# Outer div width not matching inner paragraph width

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a `div` expand or shrink depending on its inner `<p>` element width. The outer `div` contains two of those, and its width is set with max-width property so I can have a CSS transition when it readjusts its width.

On hovering a sibling div, the first inner `p` element is set to disappear while the second, which is smaller, appears. Yet the outer div shrinks all the way down to its min-width and not to that of the inner paragraph.

The following JSFiddle sums it all up. Hover your mouse on the blue box to see what's going on: http://jsfiddle.net/cq18567u/

Is there a CSS only solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason your code isn't working is because you use `position: absolute` for the `#textprev` which makes it to exit the current element flow, so what you need is to remove the `position: absolute`. This will make the `width` to the correct one, but it would look like it's not there, because by default `<p>` is a `block element`, so it the `#textprev` will be in the new line, but because you set the `height` for `#text1`, and use `overflow: hidden`, it couldn't be seen.

What you need to make it work is changing the `style` for your `paragraph`, with your current `HTML`

```
<div id="prev"></div>
<div id="text1">
    <p id="textup" class="side">Before hovering (1st paragraph)</p>
    <p id="textprev" class="side">After (2nd paragraph)</p>
</div>
```

and modified `CSS` to

```
#prev {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    background: blue;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}
#prev:hover ~#text1 #textup {
    max-width: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: all ease-in-out .5s;
}
#prev:hover ~#text1 #textprev {
    max-width: 200px;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out .5s;
}
#text1 {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    height: 50px;
    max-width: 500px;
    background: grey;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#textup {
    visibility: visible;
    background: red;
    opacity:1;
    max-width:500px;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out .5s;
}
#textprev {
    visibility: hidden;
    max-width:0px;
    background: green;
    opacity:0;
    transition: all ease-in-out .5s;
}
.side {
    text-overflow: clip;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: white;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

you change the `paragraph` with class `.side` to be an `inline-block` element, this will make it appear in the same line if there's a space. Then also you need to set the `max-width` for `#textup` on `normal` and on `hover` state, so the `transition` could work (it won't work if you declare the `max-width` only in one state), then make a different transition on `normal` and `hover` state with a `delay`, so the `width` not changing in a weird way. (remove the `transition` from `#textup` and `#textprev` on `normal` and `hover` state, then add `transition: all ease-in-out .5s;` in `.side` to see what I mean by the weird way of changing `width`)

Here's an [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyojimaru/cq18567u/15/) to see how it works.

Comment: going to accept this one as it came first and helped me understand what the issue was. nifty fix, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Also doable without `inline-block` by changing the first paragraph's height on hover, which also makes a fancy effect : [jsfiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cq18567u/16/)

Answer (score 1):

I try to change your code, but i could not realize the effect that has transition between switching two paragraph.
I removed some complex css code from your demo，just realize a base requirement without transition.

Here's my code forks yours: http://jsfiddle.net/abruzzi/cq18567u/7/
The main changed below:

```
#prev:hover~#text1 #textup{
    max-width: 0;
    display: none; }
#prev:hover~#text1 #textprev{
    display: block; }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have a block element (a `p` tag) with `position: absolute` inside another block element (a `div`).  When an inner element has `position: absolute` it means that the outer element no longer 'contains' it, and so it won't naturally wrap itself all around the inner element.  I'd try switching the CSS of `#textprev` (the second one--why do you have two?) to `position: absolute`and then moving that around.  e.g.

```
#textprev {
    postion: relative;
    top: -50px; /* to compensate for the height of your '#prev' div */
}
```

And then the animation problem, as mentioned by Kyojimaru, is just that you need to set a `max-width` on both the normal `#textup` element as well as on its `hover` pseudo-element.

Here's another [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cq18567u/17/)